# building a dom tree reading html using java

Tags: java

I am trying to build the dom tree using the scanner class in java to read a give html. Below is my implementation using a stack. for some strange reason when i try to print my tree only the root is showing up and nothing else

```
public void build() {

        root = new TagNode("", null, null);
        TagNode ptr = null;

        Stack<TagNode> tags = new Stack<TagNode>();

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String tag = sc.nextLine();

            if (tag.equals("<html>")) {

                ptr = new TagNode("html", null, null);
                tags.push(ptr);
                root.tag = "html";

            }

            else if (tag.charAt(0) == '<') {

                if (tag.charAt(1) == '/') {

                    tags.pop();
                    continue;

                }

                else if (tags.peek().firstChild == null) {

                    String temp = tag.replaceAll("<", "");
                    temp = temp.replaceAll(">", "");
                    ptr = new TagNode(temp, null, null);
                    tags.peek().firstChild = ptr;
                    tags.push(ptr);

                }

                else {

                    TagNode temp = tags.peek().firstChild;

                    while (temp.sibling != null) {

                        temp = temp.sibling;

                    }

                    String a = tag.replaceAll("<", "");
                    a = a.replaceAll(">", "");
                    ptr = new TagNode(a, null, null);

                    temp.sibling = ptr;
                    tags.push(ptr);

                }

            }

            else {

                if (tags.peek().firstChild == null) {

                    tags.peek().firstChild = new TagNode(tag, null, null);

                }

                else {

                    TagNode temp = tags.peek().firstChild;

                    while (temp.sibling != null) {

                        temp = temp.sibling;

                    }

                    temp.sibling = new TagNode(tag, null, null);

                }
            }       
        }           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete, but from looking over it, I think the problem is with

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String tag = sc.nextLine();
```

You are assuming that tags come right at the start of the line. Which may or not be true, given your html and assuming sc is a scanner, right?